# Show that the function $f(z)$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Question :

If $\phi$ and $\psi$ ae function of $ x $ and $y$ satisfying laplace's equation . Show that $f(z) =  s + it$ is analytic , where $$ s = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} -  \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \text{and} \text{ t} = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} -  \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}  $$

To prove $f(z) $ is analytic, we have to show that $f$ satisfies C-R equation and $ \frac{\partial s}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial s}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial t}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial t}{\partial y}$ are all continous

we can easily prove that  $f$ satisfies C-R equation .

Also we know that $\phi$ and $\psi$ satisfies laplace equation .  Also $\phi$ and $\psi$ are harmonic function . So  they possesses continous partial derivative upto second order.

Thus $\frac{\partial s}{\partial x} = \frac{ \partial^2 \phi}{\partial y \partial x} - \frac{ \partial^2 \phi}{ \partial^2 x} $ is continous. Similarly $\frac{\partial s}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial t}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial t}{\partial y}$ are continous.

Comment: If a function is analytic, it must have a Taylor expansion/power series expansion about some point and have a positive radius of convergence about that point (hence all of the partial derivatives). If you can re-write $f\left(z\right)$ as a power series, then by all means, this function is analytic.

Comment: @jm324354 that is a very heavy handed approach. It's much simpler than that. Just use the Cauchy Riemann equations directly.

Comment: @Cameron : Definitely you are right , but how will show that $\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}$ is continous